# Save filenames by [] and insert it to Database by Controller Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm uploading files to `destinationPath` and I'm having a problem with saving each filename when I'm trying to make a download link for those files.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $fileName = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
  $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath.$fileName.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(),file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
                    }
        if($uploaded){
            Project::create([
                'description' => $request->input('description'),
                'division' => $request->input('division'),
                'who' => $request->input('who'),
                'whom' => $request->input('whom'),
                'content' => $request->input('content'),
                'filename' => $division.'/'.$userName.'/'.$fileName
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: iwant to upload each file names . and want to make download link at each file.

Comment: hi, checkout this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads . I believe you will be able to do it from there.